# I recieve a null when I use findViewById () on a recylerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

So I am creating an application that uses a recycler view to display card view components, but the problem is that when I use `RecyclerView groceryRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById (R.id.recycler_view1)` I receive a null pointer exception. What doesn't make sense to me is that I am referencing the correct recycler view layout for the `groceryRecycler` variable.

I have done research into the null pointer exception & it only occurs if when you declare a variable but did not assign an object to it. But I did assign an object to the recycler view variable using `findViewById ()`. As a result, whenever I call a method on the recycler view variable I get a null pointer exception. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here or how to fix the problem any help will be appreciated.

Here is my recycler view layout code:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/recycler_view1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Here is my code that instantiates the recycler view:

```
package com.myapp.groceryapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class GroceryItem extends AppCompatActivity {

MyDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor cursor;
RecyclerView groceryRecycler;

private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 101;

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grocery_item);


    askForPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);

    Log.d ("red", "onCreate has ran");

    StartDatabase sd = new StartDatabase();
    sd.execute(databaseHelper);
}

public void startIntent () {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, Faan.class);
}

public void accessDataBase () {

    try {

        db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = db.query ("GROCERY_TABLE", new String[] {"NAME", "PATHS"}, null, null, null, null, null);

        db.close();

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d ("red", "accessDataBase has ran");

}

public void createRecyclerView () {

    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(GroceryItem.this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    GroceryAdapter adapter = new GroceryAdapter (GroceryItem.this, cursor);

    groceryRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);


    if (groceryRecycler == null) {
        Log.d ("red", "grocery recylcerview is null");
    }

    groceryRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    groceryRecycler.setAdapter (adapter);

    Log.d ("red", "createRecyclerView has ran");

}

public void askForPermission (String permission, int requestCode) {
    if (isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String [] {permission}, requestCode);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText (this, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, String [] permissions, int [] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult (requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults [0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Storage Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Storage Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }


}

public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted () {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private class StartDatabase extends AsyncTask<MyDatabaseHelper, Void, Boolean> {

    protected void onPreExecute () {}

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(MyDatabaseHelper... myDatabaseHelpers) {

        try {
            accessDataBase();

            Log.d ("red", "doInBackground has ran");

            return true;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            Log.d ("red", "doInBackground has ran");

            return false;

        }


    }

    protected void onPostExecute (Boolean success) {

        createRecyclerView();

      
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new GroceryAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                startIntent();
            }
        });
      

        if (!success) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(GroceryItem.this, "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

        Log.d ("red", "onPostExcecute has ran");

    }
}

}
```

Here is the exception I receive:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
    at com.myapp.groceryapp.GroceryItem.createRecyclerView(GroceryItem.java:70)
    at com.myapp.groceryapp.GroceryItem$StartDatabase.onPostExecute(GroceryItem.java:131)
    at com.myapp.groceryapp.GroceryItem$StartDatabase.onPostExecute(GroceryItem.java:112)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: From where are you calling createRecyclerView?

Comment: I am calling the createRecyclerView () from the onPostExecute () in asyncTask

Comment: Try using `findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1)` from `onCreate` and declare `groceryRecycler` as a Global Variable

Comment: @Vishnu I tried this but unfortunately I am still receiving a null pointer exception, any other ideas?

Comment: @ZahidHabib Please check whether you have this same `id` for any other elements

Comment: @ZahidHabib Check whether this whole function works from `onCreate`

Comment: @vishnu I have checked and only the recycler view layout has this `id` and the whole function does work from the `onCreate` method. It doesn't make sense why recycler view is giving a null pointer exception.

Comment: @ZahidHabib What are you using `AsyncTask` for? Is it necessary?

Comment: The possible reason may be, your started asynctask is getting finished before your setconteview() has done its work. ( Please mention where are you starting your asynctask from)

Comment: @vishnu yes the asynctask is necessary because I am using the background thread to access my SQLite database to retrieve data to display on my card views on the recycler view.

Comment: @vishnu oh, you maybe right maybe the asynctask thread is being finished before the main thread, however, how would I confirm this or solve the problem? thanks for the help

Comment: there's no need to run any of this code after the async task has completed. setup the recycler in onCreate and then keep a reference to the adapter. update the data of the adapter with the result of  the async call as it completes

Comment: @ZahidHabib Use `Logs`. You get to know about the order of execution from the logs' order in the `Logcat`. BTW, Did you fix your error?

Comment: @vishnu, unfortunately, no I still haven't fixed the error  I have implemented Logs in my code. And from the order of execution, I have found that the asyncTask thread never finished executing because the null pointer exception occurs on the recycler view.

Comment: @vishnu But from the order of execution all the methods seem to be executing as expected in the correct order, So I still am confused as to how recycler view is null unless android puts the asyncTask thread to sleep and goes back to running the main thread.

Comment: @ZahidHabib Post the whole `Activity` in the question. I will try...

Comment: @vishnu I have added the whole activity that uses the recycler view thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `RecyclerView` as the root layout, but have to wrap it into an actual layout.

Comment: We can use `RecyclerView` as root layout. Please take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#workflow) documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this to access DB from `onCreate`

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Your task here
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps. Sorry for this brief answer. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: I have implemented the code above in my `onCreate ()` with the database code in the `run ()` also the code to set up the recycler view I have put in the `onCreate ()` but recycler view is still null. I then tried to instantiate the recycler view in the `run ()` after the database code but recycler view is still null.

Comment: Now I'm having doubts whether the recycler view being null is an issue with threads because I've tried running the code on the main thread as well as the background thread and both times the recycler view is null. I don't get whats making it null.

Comment: I've also tried making the references to the recycler view, adapter & layout manager instance variables whilst instantiating the recycler view in the `onCreate`& instantiating the adapter and layout manager in the `onPostExecute ()` then setting up the recycler view in the `onCreate ()` but recycler view still ends up as null.

Comment: @ZahidHabib Sad to hear that. I'm really sorry to say that I think there is no need for an `AsyncTask` in your code - [as far as I know]. DB queries only take a small amount of time and that can be done in `UI Thread`. Sorry for disappointing you.

Comment: @ZahidHabib Also, If you are getting into android development, I strongly recommend using `Room Persistence Library` for using `SQLite Database`. [This](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) is a good starting point. Also check [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrnPJCHvNZuDihTpkRs6SpZhqgBqPU118) for video tutorials

Comment: I've tried to run the code without using asyncTask & not calling `accessDatabase ()` just instantiating the recycler view & setting it up but I still receive a null pointer exception.

Comment: thanks I will look into `Room Persistence Library` & at those video tutorials :)